# NSAttributedString with strikethrough

Tags: cocoa

I'm trying to create an attributed string with a strikethrough, however, this simple task seems to be harder to figure out than I anticipated.  Here is what I have currently (which is not working). Thanks for the help!

```
NSAttributedString *theTitle = [[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"strikethrough text" attributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, NSUnderlinePatternSolid, NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, nil]] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, the value for `NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName` must be an `NSNumber`, not a simple integer. Second, I think you have to include `NSUnderlineStyleSingle`:

```
...:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      ..., 
      [NSNumber numberWithInteger:NSUnderlinePatternSolid | NSUnderlineStyleSingle], 
      NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, 
      nil]...
```

Comment: This was very helpful. Thanks! Of note, you're missing a closing bracket to close out the `numberWithInteger:` message after `NSUnderlinePatternSolid | NSUnderlineStyleSingle` and before `, NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName`.

Answer (score 17):

You can also simply use:

```
NSAttributedString *theAttributedString;
theAttributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:theString 
            attributes:@{NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName:
            [NSNumber numberWithInteger:NSUnderlineStyleSingle]}];
```

**Update :**

Swift 2.0 version

```
let theAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: theString, attributes: [NSStrikethroughColorAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle])
```

Comment: This is wrong, you can't assign style into color attribute.
`[NSStrikethroughColorAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle]`

Answer (score 3):

```
func addAttributes(attrs: [String : AnyObject], range: NSRange)
```

*`NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName`:*
The value of this attribute is an `NSNumber` object containing an integer.

Since the `NSUnderlineStyle` enum's rawValue is Int Type, you should initialize a `NSNumber` Object with it

Swift2.1:

```
attrStr.addAttributes([NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName: NSNumber(integer: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue)], range: NSMakeRange(x, y))
```

x is the location, the start of your text

y is the length of the text

Comment: Range is not Working when i write  `NSRangeMake(0, 4)` that doesn't work , if i write `NSRangeMake(0, theAttributedString.lenght)` that  work , but my requirment to put horizontal line on only First four char on String , how can i do this .??

Comment: There is a known bug in iOS 10.3 where the strike through attribute won't work if applied in a range. As a workaround you can do: 
`attrStr.addAttributes([NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName: NSNumber(integerLiteral: 0)], range: NSMakeRange(x, y))`

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4:**

```
NSAttributedString(string: "test string", attributes: [.strikethroughStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue])
```

**Swift 5:**

```
NSAttributedString(string: "test string", attributes: [.strikethroughStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue])
```

Mind the fact that `.strikethroughStyle` and `.underlineStyle` expect an integer value (specifically an `NSNumber`), therefore we're using `NSUnderlineStyle`'s `.rawValue` in the examples.
([Setting NSUnderlineStyle causes unrecogognized selector exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46092027/setting-nsunderlinestyle-causes-unrecogognized-selector-exception))