# Setting NSUnderlineStyle causes unrecogognized selector exception

Tags: swift, swift3, nsattributedstring

I am trying to underline a string with NSAttributed string. For some reason, my lines cause the exception:

```
-[_SwiftValue _getValue:forType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

The result is supposed to be used for a UILabel within a UITableView and is created as needed.

This is the code:

```
attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: message)

if let actor = event.actor {
   let attributes = [NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName:NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle]
   var attributedActorString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: actor.shirtName, attributes: attributes)
   attributedActorString.insert(NSAttributedString(string: " "), at: 0)
   attributedActorString.append(NSAttributedString(string: ". "))                               attributedActorString.append(attributedImageStringForUrl(event.actor!.portraitImageUrl, indexPath: indexPath))
   attributedString.append(attributedActorString)
}
```

Comment: `underlineStyle` key requires an integer value (specifically an `NSNumber`) so that's why you need to use the `NSUnderlineStyle `'s `rawValue`.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Change line:

```
let attributes = [NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName:NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle]
```

to:

```
let attributes = [NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName:NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue]
```

Comment: After investigating and trying to get to the bottom of this issue, once I pin pointed the problem I came across this posts - thanks you

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 5** version of [Vlad Khambir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46092253/2395636) answer,

```
let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue]
```